# Pathname works on PC but not mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, pathname

I have an excel file with the script that allows me to generate seperate pdfs according to the data i enter into one spreadsheet. However, the code was created using Windows, and I would like to use it in mac. Can anyone help with changing the pathname of the script? The script is as follow:

```
 Sheets("6 comp").Activate
    Range("$I$93").Value = i
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    ClientName = Range("$I$94").Value
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="C:\test\" & ClientName & "_6", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not as easy as changing the filename path in this case.

I stripped out the specifics to your situation and got it to work fine on Windows. But when I first ran it on my Mac, it send the PDF right to my default printer instead of saving the file to any location.

Consistently, any attempt to edit the script on my Mac resulted in Runtime Error 1004 (even after changing back to the original code). I believe this is a bug, but there are also a lot of unsupported features on the Mac, and many are not documented by Microsoft.

Ron de Bruin's website for Mac/Windows Office topics has a great writeup on how to save a PDF in Excel Mac. http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac005.htm If you really need to get this working, that page should help.

I'd much prefer to give you a straight answer, but if you look at that page, you'll see how complicated it is.